# LottieAnimationView doesn't show in my_layout.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to use LottieAnimationView in my project but it doesn't show in my library and i can't add it.

My Module/build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' }

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.denemecalisma"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets {
                srcDirs 'src\\main\\assets'
            }
        }
    } }

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.2.0' }
```

I added it in depencies and synced build.gradle but i can't see it. Can you help me about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added MavenCentral in you gradle

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```